Getting appsettings by Options Pattern thorugh Helper Class
I'm trying to create a helper class with within a c# console application. I am using options pattern in mind so I don't have to store any sensitive data in code. So far this is what I have for the helper class.
RouteHelper.cs

public class RouteHelper
{
    private readonly WsdotConfigOptions _config;
    public RouteHelper(IOptions<WsdotConfigOptions> config)
    {
        _config = config.Value;
    }
    public Tuple<string, int> GetUrl(int routeType)
    {
        string output = CreateUrl(routeType);
        return Tuple.Create(output, routeType);
    }
    private string CreateUrl(int type)
    {
        switch (type)
        {
            case 1:
                return $"{_config.URL_BASE}{_config.URL_BORDER_CROSSING}{_config.ACCESS_CODE}";
            case 2:
                return $"{_config.URL_BASE}{_config.URL_MOUNTAIN_PASS}{_config.ACCESS_CODE}";
            default:
                return "";
        }
    }
}


How I'm trying to access it is through a class called DisplayInfo.cs Code Below
DisplayInfo.cs

private BorderInfo borderInfo { get; set; }
private MountainPassInfo mpInfo { get; set; }
private UrlSetup url { get; set; }
private Messaging message { get; set; }
private RouteHelper _routeHelper{ get; set; }
public DisplayInfo(IConfiguration config)
{
    borderInfo = new BorderInfo();
    mpInfo = new MountainPassInfo();
    url = new UrlSetup();
    message = new Messaging();
    _routeHelper = new RouteHelper(); <-- Is expecting a parameter which makes sense
}


The _routeHelper = new RouteHelper() line mentions that it expects a parameter when instantiating a new RouteHelper. I have tried to pass configuration through it but nothing seems to work. I have also tried to pass the config through the DisplayInfo.cs file for RouteHelper.cs to consume. I'm out of ideas and brain power.
Reference for below code:
Program.cs

IConfiguration configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder()
        .SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
        .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: false)
        .Build();

var services = new ServiceCollection();
services.Configure<WsdotConfigOptions>(options => configuration.GetSection("WSDOT").Bind(options));

DisplayInfo display = new DisplayInfo(configuration);

while (true)
{
    display.DisplaySelection();
}



IOptions<WsdotConfigOptions> config should be injected to constructor, if configured correctly:
builder.Services.Configure<WsdotConfigOptions>(
    builder.Configuration.GetSection("WsdotConfigOptions section name"));

If settings are in the root appsettings JSON, you could just use
builder.Services.Configure<WsdotConfigOptions>(builder.Configuration);

Options pattern in ASP.NET Core
Then, you could do the folliwng:
public DisplayInfo(IOptions<WsdotConfigOptions> config)
{
    borderInfo = new BorderInfo();
    mpInfo = new MountainPassInfo();
    url = new UrlSetup();
    message = new Messaging();
    _routeHelper = new RouteHelper(config);
}


You should be registering pretty much everything with your DI container
var services = new ServiceCollection();
services.Configure<WsdotConfigOptions>(options => configuration.GetSection("WSDOT").Bind(options));
services.AddSingleton<RouteHelper>()
        .AddSingleton<DisplayInfo>();

Your DisplayInfo class should take RouteHelper and not IConfiguration in its constructor:
public DisplayInfo(RouteHelper routeHelper)
{
   ...
}

And, incidentally, all it's other dependencies should both be registered in DI and injected in the ctor.
Then you can build your service provider and use it to instantiate DisplayInfo
var sp = services.BuildProvider();
var display = sp.GetRequiredService<DisplayInfo>();
display.DisplaySelection();

